# Obtain user data from Cognito after successful authentication with AWS load balancer

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I've a NodeJS app that serves ReactJS frontend.
I'm using AWS Application Load Balancer authentication with a Cognito user pool.
I've set up a role in my load balancer and as soon as the user enters the url of my app, the authentication is being performed and two `AWSELBAuthSessionCookie` cookies are set.

This flow works perfectly, but the thing is that I would like to obtain also the current user info from Cognito (name, email, etc..).

As i understood the other parameters like `X-amzn-oidc-data` are not available in the frontend and only available to the backend.

My questions is, how can i obtain this information assuming that i have  only the `AWSELBAuthSessionCookie` available in my NodeJS backend?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to build a back-end API endpoint that exposes that user information. Something like `yourdomain.com/api/get_user_info`. Then have your front-end ReactJS application call that API endpoint to retrieve it from the back-end.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  That is clear to me,  but how to obtain the data from aws in my express app?

Comment: In your express app, when it receives the request for `/get_user_info` the `x-amzn-oidc-data` header will be present on the request (because the express app is running behind the load balancer). At that point the express app can read that JWT, decode it, and return the value as the response to the front-end.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Does the  headers will be avaliable if the request is sent by http and not https to the api?

Comment: You should really only be sending requests for things like logged in user info over HTTPS. Amazon provides free SSL certificates to attach to your Application Load Balancer. The request between the ReactJS app and the Load Balancer should always be over HTTPS. It looks like the load balancer Cognito integration also only works over HTTPS. However the connection between your load balancer and the backend express server can be over HTTP. The header should still be there in that scenario.